# What is the minimum required compatibility level to use parallel SELECT INTO?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, parallelism

What is the minimum required compatibility level to use parallel `SELECT INTO` in SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 4):

[In SQL Server 2014 parallel DML for the `SELECT INTO` statement requires compatibility level 120.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)

**110:**

> A SELECT INTO statement always creates a single-threaded insert operation.

**120:**

> A SELECT INTO statement can create a parallel insert operation. When
>   inserting a large numbers of rows, the parallel operation can improve
>   performance.

Note, that other resources on the web state false values for the compatibility levels. These statements are quoted directly from Microsoft documentation and have been verified experimentally by me.